# Infinitely slide gallery in android

Tags: android, animation, gallery, slide, marquee

I have a gallery. But it doesnt include pictures,it is a text gallery as "emma dex angelica jasmine slyvie". I want to make an infinite slide animation or something like this ( for example marquee) on my gallery. I want to my gallery always slide.Can anybody help me??